# Reset lodash debounce after key press

Tags: javascript, lodash

in my javascript application I fire that function when input value is changed. I want defer ajax calling with lodash function `debounce`. Problem is that function works only for first key press. For instance, I stared typing and function call ajax after 1 seconds from that what I write first letter in input. I want defer calling for every key press but when I typing after 1 second function is fired every time. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

```
<custom-select :on-search="onChange"></custom-select>

function onChange (text) {
   _.debounce(function () {
      // do ajax call
   }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `debounce` a new function for each change, you should use the same "debouncer":

```js
const bounceIt = _.debounce(function () {
  console.log("pressed");
}, 1000);

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
 bounceIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text"/>
```